# Can I create a table outside of my Namecheap website's phpmyadmin database?

Tags: php, database, phpmyadmin, namecheap

My goal is to use php so I can query information from a table I created on phmyadmin and have it show up on a webpage. My is through Namecheap, I log into their cpanel and click on myphpadmin. It take me to myphpadmin where there is a database set up already. Since my site is pretty much static and I have not created a database yet I am a little confused why there are all of these tables already. See pic attached. I also notice that where the create table button usually is, is not there anymore. I have asked namecheap if I am allowed to create tables outside of the preset database but no reply for awhile. Am I able to modify an existing table or are these all being used for something I am not aware of? I am using namecheap's site builder so I'm guessing that is what it is for and I don't want to touch these table. Any idea how I can create a table outside of the website database, but one I will still be able to call and query from my webpage?

Thanks for your time.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJavX.png)

Comment: Please note: It's a MySQL database. phpMyAdmin is just one (of many) ways to access it.

Comment: Thank you so much. I thought I was going to go crazy because I could not create table in phpMyAdmin. You have opened my eyes!